# UIbutton inside UIViewControllers inside UIScrollView not getting triggered on touch

Tags: ios, swift

I'v added two UIViewControllers inside of a UIScrollView, and now I'm trying to add targets to the button inside of the UIViewControllers, I've checked the internet but none of those solutions worked for me, this is what I'm doing

inside of the main ViewController

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 2, height:0)

        let postsViewController = PostsViewController()
        postsViewController.scrollView = scrollView
        postsViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

        let chatsViewController = ChatsViewController()
        chatsViewController.scrollView = scrollView
        chatsViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

        scrollView.addSubview(postsViewController.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(chatsViewController.view)

        postsViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        chatsViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

then inside the postsViewController I'm doing this

```
 let a = UIButton()
    a.setImage(currentTheme.chat, for: .normal)
    a.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.5, left: 0.0, bottom: 1.5, right: 0.0)

    view.addSubview(a)
    view.addConstraint("V:|-200-[v0(80)]-0-|",a)
    view.addConstraint("H:|-200-[v0(80)]-0-|",a)

    a.addTarget(self, action: #selector(abc), for: .touchUpInside)
```

the add "addConstraint" is an extension function just to add constraint to views

the abc function

```
@objc func abc() {
       print("hello")
}
```

you can see the scrollView setting here

https://ibb.co/ZB1LJsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I solved my problem, the reason why the button wasn't getting trigger is because I forgot to attach the viewController of the view to the scrollview, so all I had to do is to attach the viewController as well and it worked.

```
self.addChild(postsViewController)
self.addChild(chatsViewController)
```

now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your button like this

```
let a : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

And add this after to the initialize of your UIScrollView

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested in an xcode project. I can not execute the function (button) in the other UIViewController.

By cons if you sent the #selector it works.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let scrollView : UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width))
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let TestViewController = TestViewController1()
        TestViewController.select = #selector(demande(sender:))
        TestViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(TestViewController.view)

        print("dd")

    }

    @objc func demande(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("button click", sender.tag)
    }


}
```

```
class TestViewController1: UIViewController {

    var select : Selector!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "turn_off_on_power-512"), for: .normal)
        button.tag = 2
        button.addTarget(self, action: select, for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Hoping that it helps you

Comment: this is a possible work around but it can lead to some messy code as I have more than one view controller inside my scrollview, it is preferred to set the target function inside of the ViewController itself, thank you for the work around tho :) I'm still trying to find the reason why it isn't getting triggered, I assume it's because I am adding the  "view" of the viewController to the scrollview and not adding the ViewController itself or something like that